# Term for "atmospheric ricochet" due to wrong "angle-of-attack"

Tags: terminology, rocket-science, atmospheric-science, space-travel

I watched "Apollo 13" yesterday, and they had the "angle-of-attack" problem that had to be manually solved, to prevent the ship from "*ricochet[ing] off the atmosphere like a rock skipping off a pond*".

I found and read [this](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=562456), but couldn't manage the term to further learn about this "ricochet".

**Is there a term that reflects this "ricochet"?**

Answer (score 2):

The term related to the quote you have stated, that has come up in a number of documents is **skip reentry**, some examples of its use and context are from:

[FAA article on vehicle reentry](http://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/designees_delegations/designee_types/ame/media/Section%20III.4.1.7%20Returning%20from%20Space.pdf), where they make the analogy of skipping stones.  But, it is from the Aerospace Web article [Atmosphere & Spacecraft Re-entry](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/spacecraft/q0218.shtml), where they state

> A more unusual re-entry option that merges features of both ballistic and gliding profiles is the skip entry trajectory.

Another article, from NASA about the Apollo and Soyuz missions [Reentry Vehicles: Spheres vs. Blunt Bodies](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/pao/History/SP-4209/ch3-4.htm) also use the term in the caption for the diagram (below):

[image]

> A 1963 sketch illustrating a possible **skip reentry** trajectory of the Apollo spacecraft.

Comment: It's also possible that the skip is not followed by a reentry. But a very long, lonely flight somewhere else. Assuming the speed is high enough and the angle shallow enough that is.

Comment: Yes, a complete 'bounce',the FAA article has some information and calculations for that.